# How could I make a short tune with blackberry vibrate function?

Tags: blackberry, vibration

I'd like to have a little vibration jingle play after my game is won, does anybody have a link or know how I could do this? Its a very short song so the simpler the code the better! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check following links:

- [`Creating a Blackberry Game - Let’s Hear It!`](http://www.toniwestbrook.com/archives/75), describes how to    do sound and vibration processing.
- [`Play audio in a BlackBerry device application.`](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17968/Play_audio_in_a_BB_device_app_1222359_11.jsp)
- [`Playing a sequence of tones.`](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17968/CS_playing_a_sequence_of_tones_739578_11.jsp)

Answer (score 1):

here is a code snippet you can try

```
package ravi.vibrationClass;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;


public class Vibrate extends MIDlet implements CommandListener{
    Form form;
    Display disp;
    Command vib,exit;
    public void startApp() {
        form = new Form("Vibration");
        disp = Display.getDisplay(this);
        exit = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 1);
        vib = new Command("Vibrate", Command.OK, 1);
        form.append("Press \"vibrate\" to make the phone vibrate");
        form.addCommand(vib);
        form.addCommand(exit);
        form.setCommandListener(this);
        disp.setCurrent(form);

    }

    public void pauseApp() {
    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
        notifyDestroyed();
    }

    public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable arg1) {
        if(c == vib){
        disp.vibrate(125);
        }else if(c == exit){
        destroyApp(true);
        }

    }
}
```